# My Data in table view reloaded again and again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am getting the response from json server and show that data on table view but when i scroll down the data will show again again overlaps on each cell. Anyone can tell me why this happening?My Code is below`

```
self.title=@"Table Data";

    if(check)
    {
        self.title = @"Second Page";
    }
    [self sendData];

    deliveryCases = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
    deliveryCases.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    deliveryCases.dataSource = self;
    deliveryCases.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:deliveryCases];

    myCaseName = [[NSArray alloc]init];
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [deliveryCases dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    //    Showing data in table view

    d = [deliveryCaseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    myCaseName = d.caseName;

    UILabel *caseNameLbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 100 ,50)];
    caseNameLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myCaseName];
    caseNameLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    UIFont * boldFontlblDate = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    [caseNameLbl setFont:boldFontlblDate];
    caseNameLbl.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:caseNameLbl];

    UILabel *caseDateLbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 100 ,50)];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"M/d/yyyy";
    NSString *dateString =[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    d.date = dateString;
    caseDateLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dateString];
    caseDateLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    UIFont * boldFontlblStatus= [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    [caseDateLbl setFont:boldFontlblStatus];
    caseDateLbl.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:caseDateLbl];

    UILabel *caseStatusLbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 10, 100 ,50)];
    caseStatusLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", d.status];
    caseStatusLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    UIFont * boldFontlblTrack= [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    [caseStatusLbl setFont:boldFontlblTrack];
    caseStatusLbl.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:caseStatusLbl];

    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    tableView.allowsSelection=YES;

    return cell;

}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView3
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  deliveryCaseArray.count;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 20.0;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 350 , 10)];

    UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 100 , 50)];
    lbl1.text = @"#";
    [headerView addSubview:lbl1];

    UILabel *lbl2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0, 100, 50)];
    lbl2.text = @"Case #";
    [headerView addSubview:lbl2];

    UILabel *lbl3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, 100, 50)];
    lbl3.text = @"Date";
    [headerView addSubview:lbl3];

    UILabel *lbl4 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 0, 100, 50)];
    lbl4.text = @"Status Type";
    [headerView addSubview:lbl4];

    return headerView;

}

-(void)sendData
{
        NSUserDefaults *uidSave = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSMutableDictionary *get = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [get setObject:[uidSave valueForKey:@"uid"]forKey:@"uid"];
        [get setObject:@"open" forKey:@"type"];
        NSLog(@"Dictionary Data which is to be get %@",get);
        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:get options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        NSString *jsonInputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"r=%@",jsonInputString];

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",caseTypeUrl]];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:120.0];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSError *error;
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        if (responseData != nil)
        {

            jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"Values =======%@",jsonArray);


        }

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error %@",error.description);
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Server not responding" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];
        }


    // Set up names array
   deliveryCaseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // Loop through our json Array
    for (int i = 0 ; i <jsonArray.count; i++)
    {
        //create object
        NSString *date1 = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"date"];
        NSString *protracking2 = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"protracking"];
        NSString *status3 = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"status"];

        [deliveryCaseArray addObject:[[DataObjects alloc]initWithDate:date1 andCaseName:protracking2 andStatus:status3]];

    }

    [deliveryCases reloadData];



}
    `
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. whats in  [self sendData]; method?

Comment: can u plz update what's in sendData method?

Comment: Why dont you create a custom table viewcell and work with that. It will resolve your overlap cell problem.

Comment: Dont 9 abt custom table cell

Comment: Look at it : http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: Please share code of sendData method and why you are not using prototype cell, why you are customization cells in cellForRow ?

Comment: @NishaGupta  however accepted answer works, but this approach will reduce code quality and processing speed. Why to add the view which is already added? and for removing already added view run a for loop and check if the view is already added and remove accordingly. The genuine approach is to add subview on cell when cell is nil (View is not previously added on cell). Please see my detailed answer. One more modern approach is to create all the subview's on storyboard (It provides a way in term of prototype cell). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding subview on cell's contentview each time. You should add subview only when your cell is nil. Modify this method

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [deliveryCases dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

//    Showing data in table view

    d = [deliveryCaseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    myCaseName = d.caseName;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        UILabel *caseNameLbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 100 ,50)];
        caseNameLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",myCaseName];
        caseNameLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        UIFont * boldFontlblDate = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
        [caseNameLbl setFont:boldFontlblDate];
        caseNameLbl.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:caseNameLbl];

        UILabel *caseDateLbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 100 ,50)];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        formatter.dateFormat = @"M/d/yyyy";
        NSString *dateString =[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        d.date = dateString;
        caseDateLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", dateString];
        caseDateLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        UIFont * boldFontlblStatus= [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
       [caseDateLbl setFont:boldFontlblStatus];
       caseDateLbl.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:caseDateLbl];

       UILabel *caseStatusLbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 10, 100 ,50)];
       caseStatusLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", d.status];
       caseStatusLbl.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
       UIFont * boldFontlblTrack= [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
       [caseStatusLbl setFont:boldFontlblTrack];
       caseStatusLbl.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
       [cell.contentView addSubview:caseStatusLbl];
   }
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
tableView.allowsSelection=YES;
return cell;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There is alot of redundant calculations on the other answer

Comment: @iamIcarus however the accpeted answer works, but this approach will reduce code quality and processing speed. Why to add the view which is already added? and for removing already added view run a for loop and check if the view is already added and remove accordingly. The genuine approach is to add subview on cell when cell is nil (View is not previously added on cell). One more modern approach is to create all the subview's on storyboard (It provides a way in term of prototype cell). Thanks.

Comment: indeed its just a "quick patch" solution for cell-reuse and should not be used as the correct answer

Comment: @MayankJain You are right. My approach creates an extra processing burden. And the optimal approach is to use prototype cells in storyboard, or a separate `UITableViewCell` xib. But if not that, my approach is the second best one. How do you plan on keeping the reference to the UILabel you have created? How will you change the data for the next cells?

Comment: And as for iOS 7 and above. You don't actually need to `init` a cell. The memory is allocated by the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ` method if needed. So your code won't even run properly.

Comment: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will not return nil ONLY if the prototype was declared from storyboard. Otherwise it will return nil the first time. From the looks of the OP question , it doesn't look like using storyboard to init a prototype so this answer is correct. You don't need a reference to UILabel , you can get the view by tag

Comment: And how do you plan to maintain the reference to the UILabels this way? Will you be able to change the data when the cell is reused?

Comment: By setting a tag to the UILabel and then get the get the UIViews by tag using  `viewWithTag`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82456/discussion-between-danialzahid94-and-iamicarus).

Answer (score 1):

Because of this

```
UILabel *caseNameLbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 10, 100 ,50)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:caseNameLbl];
UILabel *caseDateLbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 10, 100 ,50)];
UILabel *caseStatusLbl =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 10, 100 ,50)];
```

You are allocating label and adding it each time `cellForRowAtIndexpath` is called.

Answer (score -2):

You are adding subviews again and again in the cell when it is being reused. So that, when the first cell gets reused, it already has the labels from before, and the new labels are added as well. To get rid of them, you will have to add this after you have initialized your cell.

```
NSArray *subviewArray = cell.contentView.subviews;
for (UIView *view in subviewArray) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This will remove the older subviews, so that only the new ones are then shown.

**Update:**

As mentioned in the other answers, the above mentioned code is not the most optimal approach. The most optimal and efficient approach would be to create a `UITableViewCell` class with an interface like the following:

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak,nonatomic) UILabel *caseNameLbl;
@property (weak,nonatomic) UILabel *caseDateLbl;
@property (weak,nonatomic) UILabel *caseStatusLbl;

@end
```

and then populate the cell accordingly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: You need to add this before `myCaseName = d.caseName;`  Just try it. It will remove the older views, so that only the new views are there in the cell.

Comment: @danialzahid94 however this approach works and answer is accepted, but this approach will reduce code quality and processing speed. Why to add the view which is already added? and for removing already added view run a for loop and check if the view is already added and remove accordingly. The genuine approach is to add subview on cell when cell is nil (View is not previously added on cell). Please see my detailed answer. One more modern approach is to create all the subview's on storyboard (It provides a way in term of prototype cell). Thanks.

Comment: You add a view which was already added because you the question's code does not contain any way to retain the reference of the UILabels.